# Images don't show up during the PDF generation using PDFKit

Tags: python, pdf, pdfkit, python-pdfkit

I am scraping the data off a website inorder to then parse it into a pdf document. My downloaded HTML file has everything perfectly as I want it including the images, however, when I try to convert it to the PDF all my images dissapear.

I am not sure if it is related to this issue since my images scraped are already in their "data" form:  https://github.com/HakanL/WkHtmlToPdf-DotNet/issues/24#issuecomment-1193016633

### Configured pdfkit options

```
pdfkit_options = {
    "enable-local-file-access": "",
    'quiet': '',
    'no-images': '',
    'custom-header': [
        ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
    ],
    'encoding': 'UTF-8',
    'no-images': '',
    'disable-javascript': '',
    'disable-smart-shrinking': '',
    'no-stop-slow-scripts': '',
    'load-error-handling': 'ignore',
    'minimum-font-size': 5,
}
```

### Example Image

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8..."/>`
I get the images in this form when I scrape them from the website

I also tried downlodaing each image individually and then re-placing it on the html before creating the pdf but that wasn't successful for me since I didn't see any image show up on the PDF.